# How to work thompson's construction algorithm?

Tags: finite-automata, regular-expressions

Could someone explain to me, through an example, how the McNaughton–Yamada–Thompson algorithm works in a way that I can understand?

Thank you in advance for your helpful response!

Comment: Have you read C-H Chang's thesis? I think the presentation there is quite good. http://premsobel.info/notes/language_tools/compilers/RE2NFA2DFA.pdf

Comment: This is really good "note"! Thanks!